# javafx how to add an animation on a popup

Tags: animation, javafx, popup

I want to add a translate transition on a popup,but it failed.because TranslateTransition's parameter is the Node, and the popup is a window.

```
`javafx.animation.FadeTransition.FadeTransition(Duration duration, Node node)`
```

How can I do to add a translate transition on a popup?

Answer (score 3):

There's a way that you can move the popup window, by means of its `yProperty()`. Instead of a translate transition you can use a timeline to set this property. But since this is a read only property, we have to use a `DoubleProperty` within the transition instead and bind it to `Popup.setY()`.

For this sample, I'll use a `ContextMenu` as popup control, and create a translate animation from the top of the window to the point where the user has clicked.

We need the popup dimensions and position, and for that we need to show it. This means it will be shown, and inmediately moved to the top of the window.

The listener in `yProperty()` allows us to set the position of the popup within all the different positions interpolated during the transition.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ContextMenu cm =  new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Item 1"), new MenuItem("Item 2"));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    scene.setOnContextMenuRequested(event -> {
        cm.show(root,event.getScreenX(),event.getScreenY());

        double yIni=scene.getWindow().getY();
        double yEnd=cm.getY();
        cm.setY(yIni);

        final DoubleProperty yProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(yIni);
        yProperty.addListener((ob,n,n1)->cm.setY(n1.doubleValue()));

        Timeline timeIn = new Timeline();
        timeIn.getKeyFrames().add(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5),
                 new KeyValue(yProperty, yEnd, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)));
        timeIn.play();

    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Moving Popup");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();        
}
```